# Consequences of applying to both research and staff positions at the same school simultaneously

Tags: application, job-search, postdocs

There are some well-known universities, which I considered applying for several positions at each school (as a recent Ph.D. graduate). The potential problem is that, at each school, some of the positions of my interest are *true research* positions (either postdoctoral, or research associate), but some are *staff* positions, despite being closely related to teaching and/or research, i.e., teaching and research assistant (or manager) for education technology platforms (course development), graduate program institutional research (which includes data analysis) and some others.

While I certainly would strongly prefer a true research position, today's tight competitive environment forces me to approach the situation *pragmatically*, rather than with cautious optimism (my circumstances additionally push me in that direction - I don't have time to apply first to research ones and *wait* for response, before applying to the staff ones). Therefore, I am thinking about applying to **all** positions that I see fit, regardless of whether they are true research of staff ones.

**Questions:**

1) are there any significant reasons against applying to both types of positions *simultaneously*;

2) will simultaneous applications hurt my chances to be hired on *pure research* positions?

Comment: I think you'd hurt your chances for both types of positions, but in particular for the research positions. In research we want people who are passionate about research and would be less happy in other roles (especially long-term). Someone who applies to all kinds of positions comes across as desperate or as not caring what they have to do as long as they get paid.

Comment: @Roland: It is sad that such a smart person, as you, cannot read between the lines. I mentioned circumstances that prevent me to wait, thus, one could imagine that it is indeed due to serious life circumstances. Yes, I am desperate (_to a degree_) **at the present time** and I don't think it is a sin or that I should be ashamed of it or that makes me any less passionate about research than you (or anybody else for that matter). My educational resilience during a long period of time and consequent achievements, despite extremely difficult situations, IMHO prove that. (to be continued)

Comment: @Roland: (cont'd) But, even if my situation would be different, my decision to apply to various types of positions might be due to my _broad interests_ (which is indeed the case, too) or desire to (temporarily) **explore** other options. By your logic, all those fine researchers, who deviated from science to industry or other domains and later returned back to academia, were not passionate about research. That it is a faulty logic. By the way, I've never said that I'm applying to "all kinds of positions" - I clearly said that alternative positions are related to research & teaching as well.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that I have judged you. I haven't. You may be desperate and even have good reasons for that. Still, you don't want to give that impression when looking for a job. Broad interests are fine if that's what a job asks for. Many jobs don't. Can't say more since I don't know any specifics.

Comment: Your question has been asked many times. The main problem ["is companies don't want to hire just anyone. They want a person who wants *this job*. The other problem is you cannot convince anyone that you want *this job* when you've just applied to *every job*."](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/a-sure-way-never-to-get-hired/)

Comment: @Roland: Re: your first comment: Fair enough and point taken. Re: second comment: Thank you for the link. However, I've seen here at Academia SE, at least, several times, statements that, due to high level of competition in academia, submitting multiple applications to multiple schools are not frowned upon and is considered absolutely normal. With that in mind, _in context_ of showing that one wants "this job", I don't see essential difference between multiple submissions to schools and the same within a school. Simultaneous applications to multiple schools don't support the "this job" thesis.

Comment: If you send applications to multiple institutions/companies that's a totally different situation and even expected. The assumption there is that you are applying more or less for the same role. Applying to different institutions implies that you are a valuable potential employee and they need to compete with others to get you. It doesn't imply that you would take just any job.

Comment: @Roland: Fair enough. Thank you for clarification. While I don't see anything that would substantiate that assumption (one very well might apply to very different positions and potential employers wouldn't know that), I guess, this is the best they can do in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the same school, it would depend on how closely related those two positions are and how likely the same person is to see the same positions.

Let's say you are a biomedical scientist. Let's say that Professor Smith is hiring a postdoctoral researcher in your field, but the Center for Awesome Research that he works in is also hiring an administrative research role (let's say a grants coordinator) that you're interested in. The chances that Professor Smith *sees* both of those applications is significant, although how high it is depends on how involved in the administration of the Center he is. This could be bad. Professor Smith might think that you aren't really serious about research if you are applying for administrative roles. Likewise, the person hiring for that admin role might think you're only applying as a backup and that you really want to be a scientist. Net result is that you get neither interview.

(Now, of course, that might not happen; Professor Smith might not really care because you are excellent or reason that you are simply trying to keep options open; the admin position hiring manager may decide that this job is your true passion. Or neither may see the other's application. But it's a risk.)

Now, let's say that you apply for a biomedical research scientist position at the medical school but you also apply for a position in institutional research at the main campus. The chances that the hiring managers for those two positions will find out that you applied for the other one is probably really close to zero. So that would probably be ok.

In general, you should probably try to apply to those admin/staff positions at different institutions from where you apply for the scientist roles, but applying to admin/staff positions that are pretty separate from the science roles in terms of administrative structure would probably be fine.

Comment: Excellent advice - exactly what I was looking for (+1 and accept). I appreciate your time and effort for writing this answer.